# Filtering junit test classes from Emma Code Coverage Report

Tags: java, ant, code-coverage, emma

I have a project where I have the emma code coverage script (using ant) building and generating the tests correctly.

I have two packages
    com.myproject.abc
    test.com.myproject.abc

All of the junit tests are in the test.com.mywebsite.abc package. My goal is to NOT have the test.com.myproject.abc package included in the report (coverage.xml). I've read the emma documentation about coverage filters  and looked at several other examples, but cannot get it to work without including the junit tests in the instrumentation.

If I include the filter in the instrumentation target ... it does not instrument the junit classes, which are used for the junit test. The result is a classNotFoundException.

Here is my code.

```
<target name="emma-instrument" depends="clean" description="instruments the code">   
        <emma enabled="true">  
            <instr instrpath="${classes}" destdir="${emma.instr.dir}"  
                metadatafile="${emma.coverage.dir}/coverage.emma" merge="true" >
                <filter excludes="test.com.myproject.abc"/> 
            </instr>
         </emma>

    </target>
```

When the instrumentation happens, it moves all of the instrumented classes to emma/instrumentation - which IS included in the classpath.

```
<target name="test" depends="test_preconditions" description="run junit tests">  
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">  
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />  
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />  
            <batchtest>  
                <fileset dir="${classes}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*"/>

                </fileset>
            </batchtest>  
            <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${emma.coverage.dir}/coverage.emma" />  
            <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=true" />  
            <jvmarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"/>
        </junit>  
    </target>
```

So just to repeat - is it possible to exclude the JUNIT tests from the Emma Coverage report? What do I need to change? Thanks in advance.

I am using emma 2.1 (code coverage), java and ant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) library like so:

```
<target name="test" depends="test_preconditions" description="run junit tests">  
    <mkdir dir="${test.data.dir}" />

    <!-- Run all tests -->
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${test.data.dir}/jacoco.exec">
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">  
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />  
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />  
            <batchtest>  
                <fileset dir="${classes}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*"/>

                </fileset>
            </batchtest>  
        </junit>  
    </jacoco:coverage>

    <!-- Generate Code Coverage report
        See: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html -->
    <jacoco:report>
        <executiondata>
            <file file="${test.data.dir}/jacoco.exec" />
        </executiondata>

        <structure name="AntTestReporting">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.class" />
                    <!-- Exclude classes necessary for testing only from the code coverage report-->
                    <exclude name="**/*Test*.class" />
                    <!-- Exclude inner classes -->
                    <exclude name="**/*$*.class" />
                </fileset>
            </classfiles>
        </structure>

        <html destdir="${coverage.reports.dir}" />
    </jacoco:report>
</target>
```

You can find more info [here](http://itaffinity.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/generating-and-customizing-junit-and-code-coverage-reports-with-ant/).